TypeScript: Property 'rawAttributes' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any, any>' in Sequelize
I'm encountering a type-related error while migrating a JavaScript codebase to TypeScript using Sequelize. The error message is:
Property 'rawAttributes' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any, any>'
interface UserAttributes {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

interface UserInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<UserAttributes>, UserAttributes {}

const User = sequelize.define<UserInstance>('User', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING,
});

// Error here: Users.rawAttributes

Explanation:
While the code functions as expected in the previous JavaScript implementation and TypeScript as well (when compilation errors are ignored), I'd like to understand why it is throwing that error and if there is any alternative way to achieve the same result.
Packages used:
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.19.0",

Desired Outcome
I'm seeking a way to access model attributes in a type-safe manner while using Sequelize with TypeScript. I'd appreciate any help.

Shouldn't you use Model<UserAttributes> instead of Sequelize.Instance<UserAttributes> ?

I did try to replace Sequelize.Instance<UserAttributes> with  Model<UserAttributes>. The issue still exists.

You should indicate the type of User explicitly `const User: ModelDefined<
UserAttributes,
UserAttributes

`

